# Updating a binary vector using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a method that returns me a non-unique index list between 0 and (n-1) where n is a user-defined value. For the sake of simplicity, let us assume n is equal to five.

```
#arr = myMethod()
arr = np.array([4, 0, 4, 2])
```

The way I interpret this array is that I have the following pairs. In other words, each number in `arr` matches with its corresponding index plus one.

```
(4,1)  - (0,2)  - (4,3) - (2,4)
```

I have a numbering system for the pairs that should work as shown below. Note that since n=5, I should have 10 pairs.

```
(0,1) or (1,0) -> 0
(0,2) or (2,0) -> 1
(0,3) or (3,0) -> 2
(0,4) or (4,0) -> 3
(1,2) or (2,1) -> 4
(1,3) or (3,1) -> 5
(1,4) or (4,1) -> 6
(2,3) or (3,2) -> 7
(2,4) or (4,2) -> 8
(3,4) or (4,3) -> 9
```

In the end, I would like to have a binary vector where each pair selected gets the value of one; zero otherwise. For the example I provided above, I should get a result as:

```
res = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1])
```

I would like to perform this operation as efficiently as possible (without a for loop preferably) since I'll be working with large-scale data.  In essence, given array `arr`, I want to obtain array `res`.

Comment: Are you looking for memory efficiency or speed efficiency? The no-loop suggest speed, the large-scale suggest size.

Comment: @azelcer I definitely need the speed efficiency.

Comment: Is my answer fast enough? There is a little room for improvement, but if you need more speed you will have to use numba.

Comment: @azelcer I am currently running some tests. I don't know what ````numba```` is honestly.

Comment: I updated the solution. It should be fasster now (maybe 30% faster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. It uses list comprehensions instead of loops. I guess the sum inside the first comprehension can be replaced by a simpler expression, but I think it is good enough. It is optimized for speed and not for space (see first edit for a solution that uses less space)

```py
def positions(n, arr: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """Return the positions where ones should be."""
    if any(arr >= n) or any(arr < 0):
        raise ValueError("Invalid values in input")
    # Please note that this check is not complete:  For example, a 2 could be
    # in the position 2, and other forbidden combinations are not tested
    n -= 1
    sums = [sum(((n-i) for i in range(x))) for x in range(n)]
    rv = [sums[min(x)] + abs(x[0]-x[1])-1 for x in enumerate(arr, start=1)]
    return np.array(rv)

def pairs(n, arr: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    pos = positions(n, test)
    rv = np.zeros((n * (n - 1) // 2, ), dtype=np.int_)
    rv[pos] = 1
    return rv

test = np.array([4, 0, 4, 2])
print(pairs(5, test))
```

Output:

```
[0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1]
```